# after writing Pyspark dataFrame to csv, half of rows are missing

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to create a sample data in spark DataFrame, and write the resulting sample into csv file. number of records in dataFrame is 1000000 but once I wrote the DataFrame into a csv file, only 462690 rows have been written.

I've tried different options in write method but the problem still remains. even tried to convert spark dataframe to pandas dataframe, the same problem happens in this case too.

```
df.write.options(header='True', delimiter = ',' , quoteAll= True) \
 .csv("PresSample2.csv")
```

or

```
df2 = df.select("*").toPandas()
```

Comment: check your csv schema, it could be invalid for those lines. multiline, quote, escape and so on.

Comment: along the lines of what @Lamanus suggested, you could also try writing a small sample of dataframe to narrow down which rows in particular aren't being written and see what those rows have in commom. since it appears that almost half of your rows aren't being written, try writing the first 10 rows and see which of those are missing (i would imagine there's a good chance some of those rows will be missing). and when you see examples of specific rows that aren't being written, please add that information into your question – that would be really helpful for debugging purposes – thanks!